# How can I use reduce to calculate the intersection of multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Example:

```
myArray = [[1,2,3,4],
           [2,3,4,5], 
           [3,4,5,6]
          ];
```

Expected output:

```
newArray = [3,4]
```

How do I generate a new array with the values present in all 3 arrays?

Comment: Do you want to use `reduce` because you thought it seemed like the right way to do this, or because you just want to learn how to use it?

Comment: I do want to understand the method.  I don't know if there is a more efficient way to resolve this question.

Comment: If you want to just understand `reduce`, then a real challenging version of this problem would be to use `reduce` and *no other* array methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reducing, return an intersection of the accumulator with the current sub-array being iterated over:

```js
const myArray = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6]];
const intersection = myArray.reduce((a, arr) => (
  a.filter(num => arr.includes(num))
));
console.log(intersection);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `a.filter(num => arr.includes(num)` be better? Your code will not perform well if one of the arrays had one million items.

Comment: You're right, filtering the smaller array will be more performant, but it's almost certainly not important here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter()` to extract the matching values:

```js
let myArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]];

let intersect = ([f, ...r]) => f.filter(v => r.every(a => a.includes(v)));

console.log(intersect(myArray));
```

Comment: Personally I find the style of introducing new variables `f` and `r` "on the sly" by means of an argument with default value to be distasteful. Then, you don't even use `a` anywhere again after using it for the default for the second argument. Why not just write it as `let intersect = ([f, ...r]) => ...`? Other than that, this is a good solution, as long as you assume the OP's desire to use `reduce` was just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot @torazaburo. You are absolutely right. I've updated my answer and learnt something new as well :)

Comment: @torazaburo I've a question for you? What happened with your previous SO account? If I'm not wrong you had a very good profile here earlier?